# How to configure proxy setting in Pluggable Transport Bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, onion-routing, network-configuration

I have tried multiple times to set a proxy for the [Pluggable Transports Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports) but never succeeded.  I attempted to set the proxy in Vidalia as HTTP/HTTPS proxy. I have also tried SOCKS5 AND SOCKS4 and none of these is working.  Vidalia said:

> Vidalia was unable to apply your NETWORK setting to tor
>   Unacceptable option value : You have configured more than one proxy
>   type . (Socks4proxy|HTTPSProxy|ClientTransportPlugin)"

How to solve this error?

Comment: You can't set the proxy in PTBB, just try TBB without pluggable

Comment: TBB has been blocked by ISP , so i can not use it .

Answer (score 3):

If tor is configured to use a pluggable transport, you can't set Socks*Proxy or HTTP*Proxy.

The reason is that tor does not make connections to relays or directory servers itself anymore, but instead delegates that job to the pluggable transport, a dedicated process running outside of tor.

If you want to proxify your connection to the Tor network, you need to proxify those transports.  I don't think the pluggable-TBB has any GUI for this.  I'm also not aware of any transports that natively support being proxied, though external proxifiers might work.  This is probably not entirely trivial.

Comment: Then How to set network connection ?                    Without network connection                                   we can visit website  or  vidalia will work i.e. vidalia will redirect to firefox ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't parse this @sonu.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English .. Could you elaborate How to install pluggable transport in Tor ?